# AngularJS ngRepeat syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using AngularJS v1.3.15

I am getting a weird syntax error:

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=item%20asNaNtems

This is my template (templateUrl):

```
<div class="context-menu" ng-if="showMenu">
    <div class="context-menu-item" ng-repeat="item as items" ng-class="{disabled: item.isDisabled()}">
        <a href="" ng-click="fire(item)">
            <i class="fa" ng-class="item.getIcon()"></i> {{item.getName()}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive starts with a `$scope.items = []` in the controller function of that directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('atContextMenu', [
    function() {
        return {
            'templateUrl': '...',
            'controller': function($scope, $element) {
                $scope.items = [];
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the link says (if you have clicked on the link) you got the [syntax wrong](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). It should be `item in collection`:

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
```

Comment: @BoxMan0617 :) most of the times.. those links that comes with the error are very helpfule..

Comment: @BoxMan0617 You think, you could accept the answer, or is there anything i could add to it?

Comment: Sorry about that, it had a delay of like 15 minutes when you first answered it. Then I got busy... haha there you go though! and thanks!